# Error filling column with for loop based on predicted values

Tags: r, for-loop, prediction

**EDIT:** Now completely executable. Still thanks for reading! Questions are numbered (1./2.).

MyData is a dataframe containing a timestamp, ozone/O3-concentration, temperature and ongoing hour column each.

```
Data=data.frame(O3= numeric(2000),TEMP=numeric(2000),HOURS=numeric(2000))
Data$O3=runif(2000, min = 4, max = 207)
Data$TEMP=runif(2000, min = 0, max = 36)
Data$HOURS=c(1:2000)
Column_time=data.frame(time=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-10-09 18:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00:00"),
                           "hours"))
MyData=cbind(Column_time,Data)
```

Based on that, I fitted a non-linear model to the temperature data by hours (base code for that was given):

```
NL_Model=nls(formula=MyData$TEMP~a+b*sin((2*pi)*((MyData$HOURS+c)/8766))+d*sin((2*pi)*((MyData$HOURS+e)/24)), 
             data=MyData, start = c(a=10,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1))
```

Now I had to predict the temperature and ozone values for the next two months after the end of the original data with the model from earlier.
Creating a new dataframe and filling it with temperature data first:

```
Prediction=data.frame(O3= numeric(1416),TEMP=numeric(1416),HOURS=numeric(1416))
Prediction$HOURS=c(2001:3416)

P_time=data.frame(time=seq(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 01:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2015-03-01 00:00:00"),
                           "hours"))
P_TEMP=cbind(P_time,Prediction)
Pred_T=predict(NL_Model, P_TEMP$HOURS)
P_T=Pred_T[-c(1417:2000)]
P_TEMP$TEMP=P_T
```

1416 are the number of hours in the 2 months I have to predict.
2000 is the number of hours in the MyData dataframe, from where I want to continue.

1. My first question would be, why does the predict(NL_Model, P_TEMP$HOURS) create 2000 values and can I regulate that amount so I don't have to drop rows afterwards?

Second, the predicted ozone values are based on another model, linear this time:

```
Lin_Mod=lm(formula = MyData$O3~MyData$TEMP,data = MyData, na.action = na.exclude)
```

This gives 103.8387 for the intercept, 0.1062 for the slope.
Using a "for" loop, I tried to fill the O3-column of the P_TEMP dataframe:

```
Ozon_P=as.numeric(P_TEMP$HOURS)
for(Oz in Ozon_P) {O3_P=103.8387 +0.1062*P_TEMP$TEMP[Oz]
P_TEMP$O3[Oz] <- O3_P
}
```

This one creates an error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "O3", value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
  replacement has 2001 rows, data has 1416
```

2. Second question: What happened here? Is dropping rows back in question 1 the reason for this?

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: why 2000?

A1: Because you didn't give a properly constructed `newdata` argument to `predict.nls`. It should have been a list or dataframe with named columns that match ithe input to the model data. Read `?predict.nls`

> If newdata is missing the fitted values at the original data points are returned.

Addendum: You should have tried `list(HOURS=P_TEMP$HOURS)` or `data.frame(HOURS=P_TEMP$HOURS)` as the `newdata` argument. It's also unwise to refer to MyData$HOURS and MyData$TEMP in the formula to `nls`. The formula should not have the `data`-object name in it, just the column names.

<strike>Q2:  `P_TEMP$O3[O] <- O3_P` created error. Why?</strike>

A2: Because R does not use 0 as the lowest index to a vector, hence assignment to the [0]th item makes no syntactic sense.

Comment: Q1: Do you mean that the column name in the dataframe used for the creation of the model and the names of the df to predict from have to be the same? That's already the case, and it still doesn't work...
Q2: That's not a zero, thats a an O like in "Ozone". Or do you mean something else?

Comment: A1: It's NOT the case. The expression `P_TEMP$HOURS` does not have a name AND it's not a list either. A2: Sorry for the confusion on `O` vs `0`. The error probably does relate to the length error from passing poorly formed argument to newdata. You should have tried `list(HOURS=P_TEMP$HOURS)` or `data.frame(HOURS=P_TEMP$HOURS)`. It's also unwise to refer to MyData$HOURS and MyData$TEMP in the formula to nls. The formula should not have the data name in it, just the column names.

Comment: Q1: It worked! The transformation into a named list creates the wanted number of values. Thank you!
Q2: This one still creates an error: `replacement has 3416 rows, data has 1416`. Suddenly even more values? I'm using `Ozon_P=list(H=P_TEMP$HOURS)` now instead of as.numeric, but both give the same numbers.

Comment: Multipart Questions are deprecated on SO.

Comment: Perhaps your index should have been `seq_along(Ozon_P)`. (You didn't describe the goals of each part of the code very completely.)

Comment: Sorry about the multiple questions, first time poster here...
`for(Oz in seq_along(P_TEMP$HOURS))` in the loop solved the problem perfectly, thanks again!